# VS2017 htmlAgilityPack SelectSingleNode adds [1] to xpath?

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I want to pull elements from a page with the following code using HtmlAgilityPack:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        var htmlDoc = web.Load(@"https://www.reddit.com/r/UpliftingNews/");

        HtmlNode getChild = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[1]");


        string xPath = getChild.FirstChild.XPath + "/div[2]/div/p[1]/a";

        var node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xPath).InnerText;

        return node;
```

This doesn't work since string xPath = "/html[1]/body[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/p[1]/div[2]/div/p[1]/a". [1] is added to /html, /body and /div, essentially. Why? How do I fix this so the xPath becomes correct?

Comment: What do you **want** the code to do? What does it **currently** do?

Comment: I fixed it. The problem wasn't where I thought, I simply wasn't returning a string.